# How to remove index designated spaces from a list of file names in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm rather new to powershell and I couldn't find any documentation as to how to deal with the following issue. I just don't know how to word my question succinctly enough to produce any extremely relevant results on google.

Let's say I have a list of files in a directory:

```
$stuff = "file name1 1.csv", "file name2 78.csv", "file name3 14.csv"

"file name1 1.csv"
"file name2 78.csv"
"file name3 14.csv"
```

I would like to remove the first space after the word file and the second space after the word name, while also disregarding the .csv designation, leaving me with:

```
   "filename1"
   "filename2"
   "filename3"
```

I just want a list of these file names to loop over.  I'd like to code this so I can generalize it to any group of filenames.  Does anybody have any good ideas or can anyone point me in the right direction/documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there an actual directory with files, or just a list of filenames?

Comment: In my situation, yeah, there is.  I use `$group = (ls($path)).Name` to give me the "list" of files that I'm using.

Comment: to add on to the solution below, you can use .basename to have JUST the filename without the extension, so you dont have to remove this later on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's another way to get the job done. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates an array of strings to work with
  if you are dealing with actual file objects, you will likely need to use the `.Name` or `.BaseName` properties of those objects.
- puts that array into the `$InStuff` collection
- iterates thru that collection
- splits on the spaces
- takes only the 1st & 2nd items from that split
- joins the above items with no delimiter
- sends them to the `$OutStuff` collection
- displays that on screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> create an array of strings to work with
#    in real life, replace this block with your source instead
$InStuff = @'
file name1 1.csv
file name2 78.csv
file name3 14.csv
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> create an array of strings to work with

$OutStuff = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    # take only the 1st two items
    #    join them with no delimiter
    -join $IS_Item.Split(' ')[0,1]
    }

$OutStuff
```

output ...

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
```